# XPeekEvent Function is Blocking

Tags: c++, ubuntu-14.04, x11, xlib

I have a program that has the following basic structure:

```
while( true )
{
    if(event.type==EVENT_KEY_RELEASE  || event.type==EVENT_KEY_PRESS){
     XEvent xev;    
    XPeekEvent(display, &xev);
        if (XFilterEvent(&xev, G.win)) { printf("XFilterEvent: true\r\n"); }
        else
        {
            if(xev.type == KeyRelease || xev.type == KeyPress)
              // Get keyboard character
         }
```

}

The problem I am having is that when I press and release keyboard key , it blocks event queue until i press another key (or any other event like mouse move and ...),ideally I would like to have an X function that checks for events but does not block at all?

**UPDATE**:
I changed my program and removed infimit loop, instead of that i try to do this in a timer tread and i call this part every 30 millisecond but I am having problem yet.

Comment: What makes you certain that the event queue isn't empty when you call `XPeekEvent`?  If it *is* empty then `XPeekEvent` will block until an event becomes available.

Comment: If you want a non-blocking "is there an event of type y in the queue" function, refer to `XCheckTypedEvent`. What I see in the limited code that you provided, however, you seem to be fighting *against* X rather than *using* it (Meaning you should maybe re-think your approach and tell us what you really want to do)

Answer (score 0):

XPeekEvent peeks at an event without removing it from the queue. So if there is an odd event of some description at the front of the queue, and you call XPeekEvent in an infinite loop, it repeatedly reads that event, fails to handle it, and so the program locks up.